# Show if subset of R^2 is closed or not

Tags: general-topology

How do I show $\{(x,y) \in R^2 : x^3 + y^2 < 1 \}$

Here is what I have come up with.

We can have $x^3 + y^2 = 0$ by simply setting $x = 0$ and $y = 0$. Hence, it is bounded at $0$. So, now we want to show upper bound is closed as well.

We know for some number $z \in R$ that if $z < 1$ then $z^2 \leq z$. Hence, for some $y,x < 1$ then $y + x \geq x^3 + y^2$.

We want to show that for every $x,y$ there exists some $\epsilon$, s.t. $x + y + \epsilon < 1$.  We simply just pick $\epsilon = 1 / (2(x + y))$. Hence, because we can always find a small enough $\epsilon$, the upper bound must be open.

Hence, $[0,1)$, so it is clopen and thus not closed.

Comment: Why does $x^3+y^2=0$ iff $x=0$ and $y=0$?  Certainly $x=-1$ and $y=1$ also satisfies the equality.  Also, what does "bounded at $0$" mean?  This is describing a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (two-dimensions), but your language seems to mimic one-dimension.  This question appears to be very confused...

Comment: One approach is to use the fact that $f:{\mathbb R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=x^3 + y^2$ is continuous and $(-\infty,1)$ is an open set in $\mathbb R$ along with the knowledge of which sets in ${\mathbb R}^2$ are both open and closed. However, this depends on results you may not yet have covered.

Comment: ah, don't know why i wrote that, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Let $E=\{(x,y) \in R^2 : x^3 + y^2 < 1 \}$.Then $E=f^{-1}(-\infty,1)$, where $f:\mathbb{R^2}\mapsto \mathbb{R},(x,y)\mapsto x^3+y^2$. Since $f$ is continuous and $(-\infty,1)$ is open, $E$ is open!

Answer (score 3):

**Tip** : Let $S$ be a subset of a metric space. A set $S$ is closed if

1. The complement of $S$ is an open set,
2. $S$ is its own set closure,
3. Sequences/nets/filters in $S$ that converge do so within $S$,
4. Every point outside $S$ has a neighborhood disjoint from $S$.

The point-set topological definition of a closed set is a set which contains all of its limit points. Therefore, a closed set $C$ is one for which, whatever point $x$ is picked outside of $C, x$ can always be isolated in some open set which doesn't touch $C$.

I'm sure that the above would help you pick the correct equivalent definition of an open set and reach your solution.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, "clopen" means open *and* closed.

If you are allowed to use the "closed if and only if it contains its limit points" definition, then the following argument shows it is not closed: consider the points $(0,1-1/n)$. Each lies in your set, but their limit $(0,1)$ does not.